# jquery mobile refresh header bar

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile to make a mobile version of my website and have a question regarding refreshing cached pages.
I have a header bar and have placed a login button on it.
If the user clicks the button and successfully logs in, I replace the login button (on the server side) with a logout button.
The problem is, if I press the browser back button, the login button is still displayed.
Subsequently loaded (non-cached) pages correctly show the logout button.

I'm presuming this is because when I press back, the page is coming from cache?
Is there a way I can refresh the header bar so it shows the logout button on cached pages too?
I don't think I can just refresh the entire page in question because I don't know which pages the user has visited before they login.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of options:

1) Disable pages cache (browser back & forward buttons):

```
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
```

2) Create event catches the current page name and than manipulate the header: (something like...):

```
$("#PageName").live("pagebeforeshow", function (event, data) {

    // get current URL
    var pageName = $(location).attr("href").split("#")[1];

    // manipulate by the page name
    if(pageName == XXX){

       Header....

    }
}
```